# Cannot view revisions of this particular question

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question

Trying to view revisions of this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/274671/can-i-use-nas-without-internet-connection

results in "Oops! Something bad has happened"

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: Had the same problem earlier as well.

Comment: This is probably because of the massive number of revisions on that one post.

Comment: @MarkSzymanski - how much is massive? I've seen posts with 100 revisions which opened fine..

Comment: Try again. Looks like it opens up fine to show the list of revisions

Comment: Yep, it opens fine now @random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cleaned some bad data in the PostHistory table..  All is now well with this post.